# EC2 AWS SSH access Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy (using chef-solo and knife-solo) an app to a newly created EC2 instance, as I already did with Digital Ocean without any problem.

```
## once the EC2 instance is created and running
## from the console , I setup chef-solo

$> knife solo prepare ubuntu@ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
##  then I run the cookbook
$> knife solo cook ubuntu@ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

## in this cookbook, I have a recipe to create a 'deploy' group and a user 'myself' in this group
## I also disable root login
##  and I restrict login only to created user
## then other recipes without any problem ( postgres, rbenv, app..)

##  as the user 'myself' is created , I should be able to run ( as w DigitalOcean)

$> ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -p 22 yves@ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

But I get an error : Permission denied (publickey).
```

Why doesn't this run fine as with DigitalOcean, is there a trick with AWS EC2?

Answer (score 0):

the Ubuntu AMI used to launch the instance is different from the one used w DigitalOcean ...

```
in /etc/ssh/sshd_config by default
   PasswordAuthentication no
```

so I need to add a task in my [ssh] recipes

```
# enable Password Authentication for new user
bash "allow Password Authentication to created user" do
  code <<-EOH
  sed -i '/PasswordAuthentication.*/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  echo 'PasswordAuthentication yes' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  EOH
notifies :restart, "service[ssh]", :delayed
not_if "grep -xq 'PasswordAuthentication yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
end
```

and I can add the SSH key for the new created user 'deployer'

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -p 22 deployer@ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```